# How to send big picture push notification in ios like android big picture?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, notifications, ios10

I want to display big picture in iOS app when push notification comes, I checked in android it is displaying big picture when we expand that notification , how I can get same thing in iOS with object-c language.

I heard some where that we can send that kind of push notifications in iOS v10, I had searched for that but that is in swift language, how can I get same thing in objective-c or how can I merge swift language code with objective-c language.

iOS -10 supports big picture with gif image also: https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-send-ios-10-notifications-using-the-push-notifications-api/

I want to use same thing in objective- c

Comment: you got any reference in objective c

Comment: From ios 10 onwards you can send like big image or gif image or video, but below version I didn't get any link to refer.And that library is in swift language not in objective c

Comment: Ok thanks. I also got some Reference in Swift language but not in Objective c.

Comment: like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoWUIJMOjdI&feature=youtu.be